# Delay push notification delivery-Estimote/.net

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, .net, ibeacon

I have already implemented push notification which is working fine.
I am working with Estimote's beacons, where when a device comes in a proximity, i make a call to server and than server sends a push notification.
The problem is, i am trying to setup restrictions, like, send 10 notification per hour.

is it feasible to handle restrictions from .net side? since in iPhone side, have major concerns,like first download restrictions form the server when a device comes in proximity and than than make a call to server for Push, as per the restriction set.

What is the Best approach to achieve this.?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delay in receiving APN on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807456/delay-in-receiving-apn-on-iphone)

Comment: No its not, that post is having issue due to server. I am programmatically trying to delay Push notification and number of push notifications to be delivered.